# How to animate the creation of this arc in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to include an animation in bellow code that will create the circle starting from 0 to 360.
I would like to know what do I need to include to be able to animate the draw of the circle.

I've tied to add an increment of 1+ in order for each frame to grow the arc to 1 degree.

```py
from tkinter import *
h=359
w = Canvas(Tk(), width=1000, height=600, bg='white')

def circular_arc(canvas, x, y, r, t0, t1, width):
    return canvas.create_arc(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, start=t0, extent=t1-t0,
                             style='arc', width=width)

midx = 1000/2
midy = 600/2
r1 = 200
circular_arc(w, midx, midy, r1, 0, h, 20)


w.pack()
mainloop()
```

I expect to see a circle created form 0 to 360 gradualy.

Comment: is not, I don't want to move it I want to generate on screen

Comment: ***"I don't want to move it"***: The principle is the same, instead of move do `.itemconfigure(<item id of arc>, extent=<new extend value>)`. Read [Canvas.create_arc-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_arc-method). You don't show any attemp to ***animate***, [edit] your question accordingly.